# Qt4 using a Class to create a SLOT to control a QWebView's setTextSizeMultiplier using CONNECT with a QSLIDER

Tags: c++, qt, class, connect, slot

Using Qt4, how do I create a Class to create a SLOT to control a QWebView's setTextSizeMultiplier using CONNECT with a QSLIDER.

My code: (thesliderbar is QSlider and vweb is QWebView)

```
class webextras
{
    Q_OBJECT::Ui_ywr *pui;

public slots:
    void wtresize(int wtr)
    {
        pui->vweb->setTextSizeMultiplier(wtr);
    }
};

connect(thesliderbar,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),webextras,SLOT(wtresize(int)));
```

I'm getting errors for the connect();.

Errors:

**ywr.cpp:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token**

**ywr.cpp:-1: In constructor ‘ywr::ywr(QWidget*)’:**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First in order your class to support signals/slots it must inherit from QObject.

Second you should use the macro `Q_OBJECT` which is needed from the moc tool:

> The Meta-Object Compiler, moc, is the program that handles Qt's C++
>   extensions.
>
> The moc tool reads a C++ header file. If it finds one or more class
>   declarations that contain the Q_OBJECT macro, it produces a C++ source
>   file containing the meta-object code for those classes. Among other
>   things, meta-object code is required for the signals and slots
>   mechanism, the run-time type information, and the dynamic property
>   system.

So your class should be:

```
class webextras : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT;

public slots:
    void wtresize(int wtr)
    {
        pui->vweb->setTextSizeMultiplier(wtr);
    }
};
```

What is the `Ui_ywr *pui`? `Q_OBJECT` is a macro, you cannot declare it like the way you did.

Comment: Thank You :) I decided to add the function to an existing class and it worked.